# How to adjust the length of input

Tags: css, angular, dart

I am using https://dart-lang.github.io/angular2_components_example/ components and want to adjust the length of input box to the box:

[image]

As you can see on the picture, the inputbox should be as long as the black box above. How can I do adjust it in css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<material-input floatingLabel style="width:250px">
```

or

```
<material-input class="foo" floatingLabel>
```

and

```
material-input.foo {
  width: 250px;
}
```